# Rails development environment trying to connect to AWS database, not localhost's PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an existing Rails app which was previously running successfully on my local laptop (running OSX) with the database stored locally in PostgreSQL. I've also successfully deployed the Rails app to Elastic Beanstalk with the database in RDS - the hosted site is still running.

I haven't touched the localhost version for months and tried to start it today using `rails server -e development`, but when visiting http://localhost:3000/ as per usual, I get a PG error message

> PG::ConnectionBad at / FATAL:  password authentication failed for user
>   "murjfphxxxxxx" FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "115.x.x.x",
>   user "murjfphxxxxxx", database "d37vsvehxxxxxx", SSL off

The same error is thrown in the Rails console. It seems that the development version is trying to connect to the AWS database, rather than the localhost database, but I can't figure out why.

/config/database.yml lists the development environment as:

`development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <my-app>_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: <password>`

I can connect to the localhost PG database via PSQL and see the contents, so it appears that the localhost PG database is valid.

Why would the development environment try to connect to the AWS version of the database? Please let me know if you need any further information to debug this.

Using ruby-2.3.1, Rails 4.2.0, PostgreSQL 9.6.0.0

Comment: Have you tried running `rails s RAILS_ENV=development` just to see if its using the proper environment?

Comment: @Coolness sorry I meant to mention that I had already tried that - I've edited the question. It made no difference to the result

Comment: do you have `DATABASE_URL` var in your env? (you can check by typing `env | grep DATABASE_URL` in terminal)

Comment: @esse bingo! Do you want to put that as an answer, and I'll accept it. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `DATABASE_URL` in your env. You can check by typing `env | grep DATABASE_URL` in terminal.

If so, try unsetting it with `unset DATABASE_URL`.

As said in [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> If you have both `config/database.yml` and `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` set then
>   Rails will merge the configuration together. To better understand this
>   we must see some examples.
>
> When duplicate connection information is provided the environment
>   variable will take precedence.